# "No protocol specified" after "sudo atom"

Tags: fedora, sudo, atom-editor

Sudo works only with some of my applications. For example `sudo vi` or `sudo gedit` works, but `sudo atom` returns an error

> No protocol specified

I tried to follow steps from [another stackoverflow question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/no-protocol-specified-when-running-vim-with-sudo) but:

- `visudo -f /etc/sudoers` returns "Permission denied".
- I don't have any `.Xauthorit`y file in `$HOME` nor I have any `$XAUTHORITY` set.

(I am using fedora.)

Comment: login as root, then visudo -f /etc/sudoers

Comment: What is `atom`? It's not installed on my system. Can you link to a distro repository page or the project's web site? Based on the very limited information you have provided, I suspect it requires additional command-line parameters, which you are not providing. This is not likely to be a `sudo` issue, but rather an `atom` (whatever that is) issue.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Atom is an IDE (https://atom.io)

Answer (score 3):

Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

```
xhost si:localuser:root

sudo   your-graphical-app
```

Restore the default permissions:

```
xhost -si:localuser:root
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I'm running Fedora with Wayland, which apparently doesn't support running applications under a different user (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1680591#p1680591).

However, you can easily achieve what you want (editing a file that is owned by root) with the following command:

```
atom admin://path/to/file
```

In other words: just prepend `admin://` to a path that needs root privileges.

Then again, this might not work for you as gedit seems to do fine. (In my case it failed too.)