# "perl/Tk unusable, cannot create main windows." when running using "sudo"

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, opensuse, x-server, xauth

Full error message for `sudo /usr/local/bin/tlmgr -gui` (TeX Live 2017 manager) I'm getting on my OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with Gnome 3:

```
No protocol specified
perl/Tk unusable, cannot create main windows.
That could be a consequence of not having X Windows installed or started!
Error message from creating MainWindow:
  couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 53.
Tk::MainWindow->new() at /usr/local/bin/tlmgr line 4704.
```

No such error message when starting it without `sudo` (can't use it this way though since I installed it system-wide).

Same result if

- doing `sudo -H`
- doing it inside `sudo -i` (should be the same as `sudo -H` AFAIK)
- using `pkexec` instead of `sudo` (apparently [the new replacement for `gksu`/`gksudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo)?)

Then I tried being clever and played around with the X authority file (got the idea from posts such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8250):

```
ln -s /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority /root/.Xauthority

# inside sudo -i then
export XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority
```

After that I'm getting the error message with the following first two lines (and the rest the same as previously):

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyperl/Tk unusable, cannot create main windows.
That could be a consequence of not having X Windows installed or started!
```

Output for `xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a
#ffff#6c696e75782d71317863#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a
```

For `sudo xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7e608058d97a6bf4ae346879f4f5fd46
```

For `ssh -X localhost xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  faaf2ba1724d5efe85aa5ef6cb4fcc52
```

For `ssh -X root@localhost xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e8168ff05f56458663f187ec38f744fe
```

#### After `sudo ln -sf ~/.Xauthority /root`

Output for `xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a
#ffff#6c696e75782d71317863#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a
```

Output for `sudo xauth list`:

```
linux-q1xc/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  faaf2ba1724d5efe85aa5ef6cb4fcc52
```

Error message is again the first one.

`xauth list` output inside `su -` or using `sudo -E` (both where it works):

```
linux-q1xc/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a                                                                                                                        
#ffff#6c696e75782d71317863#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fa445a3c038b19300e8e45d4ae0ae55a
```

(Same as the first one.)

---

Works with `ssh -X localhost tlmgr -gui`. Also works inside `su -` and using `sudo -E`.

What is the underlying issue and how can it be solved?

Comment: Does it work with standard ssh X tunneling?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Interestingly enough, it does, even with root (and I just noticed that I have root login activated for my SSH server).

Comment: What is the output of `xauth list`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Added.

Comment: Try `ln -sf /home/your_user/.Xauthority /root/`.  After that `xauth list` and `sudo xauth list` should have the same output.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Interestingly enough it works inside `su -`, which as opposed to `sudo -i` has e.g. `XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME` and `DISPLAY` set. Also `XAUTHORITY` is set to `/root/.auth<RANDOM>`.

Comment: Lack of `DISPLAY` (or a -display option, if the command accepts it) would be a showstopper. The answer to this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec tells how to get pkexec to retain your `DISPLAY` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the problem has to do with `DISPLAY` not being preserved with `sudo`, therefore using `sudo -E` is a possible solution.